# Showing a dialog when Avalonia main window is closed

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am making an app with Avalonia that should show a Save Changes dialog when the user attempts to close the main window without saving.

I've already tried to bind to the `Closing` event and show the dialog like this:

```cs
        Closing += async (_, args) =>
        {
            var dialog = new YesNoDialog(); 
            var model = new YesNoDialogViewModel
            {
                Prompt = "Save changes before closing?"
            };
            dialog.DataContext = model; 
            var result = await dialog.ShowDialog<bool>(this);
            if (!result)
                args.Cancel = true;
            else
                SaveChanges();
        };
```

But the window just closes and the dialog never appears. When debugging, the `await` statement immediately returns false without showing anything. I also tried

```cs
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog<bool>(this).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and made the lambda non-async, but this time it just froze the entire UI and the dialog still didn't appear.

What would be the best way to implement this "show dialog on close" feature?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but I was integrating the Dialog as a Panel in my main Window. I was not using a separate Dialog.
Here's how I fixed it:

1. Use a boolean that records if the user has validated the exit of the application (ex: `UserWantsToQuit`, default: false)
2. In the `OnClosing` method, if `UserWantsToQuit == false`, cancel and launch a Task to display the dialog (ex: `MyShowDialog()`)
3. In the `MyShowDialog` method, if the user validates that he wants to quit, we set `UserWantsToQuit` to true and we can call Close.

   > ***Warning:*** As we are in a Task and as the display of the Dialog must be done in the UI Thread, it is necessary to use `Dispatcher.UIThread` to trigger the display of the Dialog

OnClosing Example:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!UserWantsToQuit)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;

            Task.Run(() => MyShowDialog());
        }

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```